# Filter gridview in form in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to use a gridview in a form. The idea is to insert multiple selected rows from the gridview into the table. I've managed to get the gridview in the form. But when I'm filtering it it is running the insert command in stead of filtering.

Also, please let me know if there is any better way to do this.
Code of my _form

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Rmtemplate;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Rawmaterial */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="rawmaterial-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'usedate')->widget(
                DatePicker::className(), [
                // inline too, not bad
                 'inline' => false, 
                 // modify template for custom rendering
                //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'todayHighlight' => true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                ]
            ]);?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Rmtemplate::find()->select('productname')->distinct()->orderBy(['productname' => SORT_ASC,])->all(),'productname','productname'),
                'language' => 'en',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Charge...', 'id' => 'productid'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel2,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

                //'id',
                //'productname',
                [
                'attribute'=>'productname',
                'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Rmtemplate::find()->orderBy(['productname' => SORT_ASC])->asArray()->all(), 'productname', 'productname'),
                'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true],
                                    ],
                'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Charge Name'],
            ],
                'rmname',
                'qty',

                //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ],
        ]); ?>
        </div>
    </div>  



    <?= $form->field($model, 'rmname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'useqty')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'unitcost')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>



    <?= $form->field($model, 'chargenumber')->textInput()->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>



    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<?php
/* start getting the chargeno */
$script = <<<EOD
  $(window).load(function(){
  $.get('index.php?r=rmprod/rawmaterial/get-for-chargeno',{ orderid : 1 }, function(data){
      //alert(data);
      var data = $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#rawmaterial-chargenumber').attr('value',data.chargeno);
  }
  );
});
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the chargeno */
?>
```

Code of Controller Action

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Rawmaterial();
        $searchModel2 = new RmtemplateSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Code of create.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Rawmaterial */

$this->title = 'New Charge';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Rawmaterials', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="rawmaterial-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
        'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

The error - 
[image]

**Update:**
On ScaiseEdge's answer I've updated the _form and the Controller action looks like below.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Rawmaterial();
        $searchModel2 = new RmtemplateSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if ($_POST('submit')  == 'create_update' )  {
        // then perform the insert 
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                    'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                ]);
            }
        }  else {
             // no insert  but render for filter ..
            return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                    'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                ]);
        }

    }
```

**Error:**
[image]

**Update 2**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Rawmaterial();
        $searchModel2 = new RmtemplateSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if (!$request->isAjax) { 

        if ($_POST('submit')  == 'create_update' )  {
        // then perform the insert 
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                    'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                ]);
            }
        }
        }  else {
             // no insert  but render for filter ..
            return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                    'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                ]);
        }

    }
```

**Error**
[image]

**Update 3**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Rawmaterial();
        $searchModel2 = new RmtemplateSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if (isset($_POST('submit'))) { 

        if ($_POST('submit')  == 'create_update' )  {
        // then perform the insert 
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                    'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                ]);
            }
        }
        }  else {
             // no insert  but render for filter ..
            return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                    'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                ]);
        }

    }
```

**Error**
[image]
**Update 4**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Rawmaterial();
        $searchModel2 = new RmtemplateSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

            if ($_POST('submit')  == 'create_update' )  {
            // then perform the insert 
                if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                } else {
                    return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                        'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                    ]);
                }
            }
            }  else {
                 // no insert  but render for filter ..
                return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
                        'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
                    ]);
            }


    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to the fact the filter value is submitted for perform the search.
You could override this behavior  adding a value to the submit button

```
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', 
      ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary',
    'name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'create_update']) ?>
```

and in the controller/action (insert and update)   check the content of the submit  button

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    if ($_POST['submit']  == 'create_update' )  {
          // then perform the insert 
      }   else {
         // no insert  but render for filter ..
}
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, I've tried the solution and not sure about how to use the if statement in the controller action. I've added my present situation and error in the question.

Comment: @Tanmay  Hi ... i have changed my answer  checking if isAjax .. before testint $_POST .. because could be that in this case $_POST is not valid

Comment: @ scaisEdge Hi..I'm getting undefined variable error now. Have added it in the question with the action create code. Am I using the if statements correctly?

Comment: used. It gives the earlier error - "Function name must be a string"

Comment: I've updated the present code and error  in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Tanmay   . i'm sorry  wrong sintax is an array  and i have used wrong brackets  . i have update the answer

Comment: Now I'm getting a completely white page. Nothing is there.

Comment: @Tanmay  but you are trying to insert or update or are you trying to filter?

Comment: I've changed the curly bracket position a bit(I've added in the question). Now I'm getting the gridview filter in the form. When I'm filtering it the data is not inserting. That's fine. But the gridview is not filtering as well. Some code is missing here and not finding what. Or the rendering might be wrong. Please suggest. I've added current situation in the question. First let me filter it and select what rows I want to insert. Then I'll try to insert it.

Comment: The code  seems right .. the filter is based on searchModel and dataprovider  and this code is not changed .. .. .. so   i don't know why the filter don't work.. Are you sure your filter work properly in this case .. I repeat  to me the filter problem seems not related  to the original question .

Comment: This Works fine. I made some typo that's why it was not working then. Thanks a lot.